# Getting an epoch timestamp range that represents the current day

Tags: python, range, epoch

I'm trying to get the epoch range (two timestamps) that represent the current day, in the EST timezone. So, the epoch timestamp from 12:00 AM EST to 11:59 PM EST. I don't know much about the way epoch timestamps work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you mean "seconds since epoch" -- a value that is normally used by unix systems internally. Advantage is that you just need one integer value to represent the time stamp.

You can use mktime to convert a time&date value to an "seconds since epoch":

https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.mktime

To get the range, just call mktime two times. For the first value, just call it with time set to 0:00:00. For the second value, you can either fill with 23:59:59 or (what I would prefer) with 0:00:00 on the next day (giving an half-open interval).

See here, how to fill the input parameter:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time

Note that the result is a float value. The fractions are fractions of seconds, if needed. Just call `int(result_value)` when you just need the seconds as integer.